# live HTML table source updated by multi user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, datatables

sorry for the strange question but I've been stuck on this for a few days now....

We're trying to connect all of our sales from multiple locations, and query our warehouse quantity. 
Unfortunately it's too close to Christmas to be able to make POS software upgrades, so I've been tasked with writing the middleware.

Currently, I'm copying all .mdb from all shopfronts, running linq to join warehouse quantities and auto generating a HTML table all in VS Win Forms and C#.

So, What I'm wondering is, where should I go from here?

Ideally I'd love the final result to be a webpage with an interactive table in which users can remove/hide rows (once item is picked), export final results picked/non picked and have all this accessed simultaneously and live updated on tablet pc by multiple users who are picking.

I've tried the jQuery DataTables plugin but unless I'm incorrect it doesn't support simultaneous editing and have tried everything. (I'm very new to jQuery).

If someone could please point me in the right direction, even if it means I should change database types like sql, use php, or even use carrier pigeons etc they will be my hero!!!!

Comment: Your best bet IMHO, is to use Datatables and implement a server connection and have the table update itself on the displayed page periodically. However, the system you're describing in non-trivial and will take a significant amount of work to produce regardless of the tools you use. Im not sure you can reasonably complete this in time to help your christmas rush. All that said, this is not really a good fit for SO. The current question is far too broad

Comment: Thanks D0D, sorry for the trouble and vagueness, I'll try dataTables again :)